# What is the best way to vertically center text with CSS (in my situation)?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a navigation bar, and this navigation bar should be split into columns with CSS grid, so that I can add my different links into these different blocks.
Here is the HTML and CSS:

HTML:

```
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="navContainer">
    <a href="index.html" id="profile" class="link">Andreas Nagelgaard</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

#profile {
  grid-column-start: profile;
}

#navContainer {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [profile] 2fr [emptySpace] 3fr [otherone] 1fr [othertwo] 1fr [otherthree] 1fr;
}

.link {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Now, I want to have the links centered vertically within the navigation bar, and I have found a few different methods: using flexbox and `align-items` (this might create problems with the spacing, because I want to have an empty space in the middle), using `vertical-align: middle` and `display: table`, but this could lead to far too many containers.
What is the best solution for my situation (without using flexbox)?

Comment: what about line-height: 90px; ?

Comment: flex is the newest approach, table was used before flex was invented but there is no "best" way

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add line height:

```css
#profile{
  line-height:90px;
}
```

Here you give #profile the line-height size same as navbar height so it'll come center vertically

Or

```css
#profile{
   margin: auto 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Display: flex** and **auto y-margin** just like this, you can ignore **white-space: nowrap;** part its just to show you a proper result on StackOverflow:

```css
#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

#profile {
  grid-column-start: profile;
}

#navContainer {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [profile] 2fr [emptySpace] 3fr [otherone] 1fr [othertwo] 1fr [otherthree] 1fr;
}

.link {
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: auto 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="navContainer">
    <a href="index.html" id="profile" class="link">Andreas Nagelgaard</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this...

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">Everything here will be in the exact center</div>
</div>
```